# How to get the details of a person whose earning in a day is greater than or equal to their earning in the previous day

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Table: Info

[image: Table]

Sample Output:

[image: Sample Output]

This is a college exercise. I have just started learning SQL and don't understand how can you select data from two different rows of a column and create different columns in the sample output. My attempt is completely useless so I'm not putting it here as I only know how to select separate columns.

Thank you in advance

Comment: At StackOverflow, it's common that you show us some effort, your current query and we will point you in the right direction. One tip for now: you could use the ROW_NUMBER() function. Good luck.

Comment: Is your database mysql or SQL Server? You've tagged both...but the answer could be different depending on which one you're using. Please only tag the relevant technology.

Comment: and Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Lag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) here as well which is supported in both MySQL and SQL server. `LAG()` is a "Window Function" that creates chunks of records (`PARTITION BY`) for distinct values (here we use `person`). It also orders the records in those chunks/windows/partitions and allows you to run logic against them. `LAG()` picks the previous record's value inside that ordered partition. In this case, it gets the previous day's `earning` for each record's `person`.

```
SELECT person, 
    earning as current_day_earning, 
    LAG(earning) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY day) as previous_day_earning 
FROM info;
```

Toss that in a subquery and filter:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT person, 
            earning as current_day_earning, 
            LAG(earning) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY day) as previous_day_earning 
        FROM info;
     ) curr_and_prev
 WHERE current_day_earning > previous_day_earning
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a LEFT JOIN of your Info table with itself. As such:

```
SELECT B.PERSON, B.DAY, B.EARNING, A.DAY PREVIOUS_DAY, A.EARNING PREVDAYEARNING
FROM INFO A
LEFT JOIN INFO B ON A.PERSON=B.PERSON AND B.DAY=A.DAY + 1 AND B.EARNING>=A.EARNING
WHERE B.EARNING IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go bruh

```
create table #temp_Data
( person varchar(1) null
, earning int null
,day int null
)

insert into #temp_Data values
('A',10,2)
,('A',20,3)
,('B',20,1)
,('B','5',2)
,('B',10,3)
,('A',30,4)

select * from (
select *
,Row_num = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by person order by earning desc )
from #temp_Data
) a
where a.Row_num = 1
```

Comment: This is close, but it will just return the most current record for each person, not any record where the person's previous day's pay was less than the current record's pay.

Comment: oh that was an easy fix.. edited the code to order by earning not day how I had it originally.

Answer (score 0):

Declare @MyTable table(Person Char, Earning int, [WorkDay] int)

Insert into @MyTable(person, Earning, Workday) values ('A', 10, 2) 
Insert into @MyTable(person, Earning, Workday) values ('A', 20, 3)
Insert into @MyTable(person, Earning, Workday) values ('B', 20, 1) 
Insert into @MyTable(person, Earning, Workday) values ('A', 30, 4) 
Insert into @MyTable(person, Earning, Workday) values ('B', 5, 2)
Insert into @MyTable(person, Earning, Workday) values ('B', 10, 3)

Select 
a.person, a.Workday as a_day, a.Earning as PreviousDay,  b.workday as b_day, b.earning as Earning

from 
@MyTable a 
join @MyTable b on  a.Person = b.person and a.[WorkDay] +1  = b.[WorkDay]

where b.Earning >= a.Earning